# How can I use the mite-api to automatically save data in a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to save data from my mite-account (time tracking data) in a google spreadsheet via API call.

I already read the documentation on the "UrlFetchApp" and the mite-API, but the way I tried to implement it nothing happens.

This is the Example Code shown on the Mite-Site:
"curl https://demo.mite.yo.lk/projects.json?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY"

```
var apiKey = 'myApiKey';

var url = 'https://'myCompanyName'.mite.yo.lk/time_entries.json?api_key=' + apiKey + '&group_by=month,customer,project&from=2019-01-01&to=2019-02-01';
var options = {
    'method' : 'get'
  }
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Comment: Did you log the response?

Comment: In the documentation they mention to setup a user agent var options = {
    "method" : "get",
    "headers":{"User-Agent": "your_app/v0.1 (https://your_link_or_email); mite-rb/0.5.3"}
  }

Comment: @St3ph yes, with that options variable everything works fine. thank you very much :)

Comment: I posted a real anwer with some text for better SEO and future reader do not hesitate to mark it as bet answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to Mite.yo.lk by API you have to include a User-Agent reference in the headers, so request is :

var apiKey = 'myApiKey';

```
var url = 'https://'myCompanyName'.mite.yo.lk/time_entries.json?api_key=' + apiKey + '&group_by=month,customer,project&from=2019-01-01&to=2019-02-01';
var options = {
    "method" : "GET",
    "headers":{"User-Agent": "your_app/v0.1 (your_link_or_email); mite-rb/0.5.3"}
  }
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Based on documentation user agent must be define respecting this rule :

---

*Please set the User-Agent HTTP header for all of your requests. The header should include the name of your application or script, and a link or e-mail address, so we can get in touch in case there are any problems. Bonus points for including the used library including its version number. Here's an example:*

*User-Agent: mite.app/v1.1 (https://github.com/yolk); mite-rb/0.5.3*

*This may become a requirement in the future. To design your agent future-proof, please set the user-agent header in each and every client.*

---